# how to insert into a table the file name loaded with filechooser in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, scenebuilder, filechooser

I'm trying to populate the table with the file name taken by filechooser, in fileName column, how can I include the filename in this column of Tableview ?

**this is a Interface with sceneBuilder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<VBox fx:id="VBox" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
  <children>
    <MenuBar fx:id="MenuBar" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu fx:id="Help" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem fx:id="GuidaOnline" mnemonicParsing="false" text="GuidaOnline" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="Manuale" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Manuale" />
                  <SeparatorMenuItem fx:id="Separator" mnemonicParsing="false" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="About" mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="Riconoscimenti" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Riconoscimenti" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <SplitPane fx:id="Split1" dividerPositions="0.289532293986637, 0.7806236080178174" focusTraversable="true" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <items>
        <AnchorPane fx:id="Anchor1">
          <children>
                  <TabPane fx:id="Tab1" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="391.0" prefWidth="245.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                    <tabs>
                      <Tab fx:id="TabElenco" text="Elenco suoni">
                           <content>
                              <ScrollPane fx:id="Scroll1" prefHeight="362.0" prefWidth="227.0">
                                 <content>
                                    <TableView fx:id="Table1">
                                      <columns>
                                        <TableColumn fx:id="colCount" prefWidth="26.0" text="#" />
                                        <TableColumn fx:id="colName" prefWidth="124.0" text="NomeFile" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="colDate" prefWidth="79.0" text="Data" />
                                      </columns>
                                    </TableView>
                                 </content>
                              </ScrollPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                      <Tab fx:id="tabRegistra" text="Registra" />
                    </tabs>
                  </TabPane>
                  <Button fx:id="btnAggiungi" layoutX="18.0" layoutY="437.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#AddFileAudio" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="Aggiungi" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnRimuovi" layoutX="145.0" layoutY="437.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="Rimuovi" />
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <ScrollPane fx:id="Scroll2" prefHeight="551.0" prefWidth="496.0" />
        <AnchorPane fx:id="Anchor2" prefHeight="551.0" prefWidth="205.0">
               <children>
                  <Label fx:id="lblAnalisiSing" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" opacity="0.5" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Analisi singola:" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnSpettrogram" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="51.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Spettrogramma" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnSpettro" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="83.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Spettro" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnFormanti" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="117.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Formanti" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnPicchi" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="150.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Picchi" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnIntensita" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="183.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Intensità" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnPulsazioni" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="217.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Pulsazioni" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnAnalizza" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="395.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Analizza" />
                  <Label fx:id="lblAnalisiCom" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="352.0" opacity="0.5" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Analisi completa:" />
               </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </items>
    </SplitPane>
    <HBox id="HBox" fx:id="Hbox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <children>
        <Label fx:id="LeftStatus" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="-1.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
          <font>
            <Font size="11.0" fx:id="x3" />
          </font>
          <textFill>
            <Color blue="0.625" green="0.625" red="0.625" fx:id="x4" />
          </textFill>
        </Label>
        <Pane fx:id="Pane" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <Label fx:id="RightStatus" font="$x3" maxWidth="-1.0" textFill="$x4" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
      </children>
      <padding>
        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
      </padding>
    </HBox>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

**this is the class main**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("StartGUI.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,900,550);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**this is a controller**

```
/**
 * Sample Skeleton for 'StartGUI.fxml' Controller Class
 */

package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableArray;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import utility.TableFileValue;
import utility.Person;
import utility.PopulateTable;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;

public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private URL location;

    @FXML // fx:id="Help"
    private Menu Help; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btnSpettro"
    private Button btnSpettro; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="lblAnalisiCom"
    private Label lblAnalisiCom; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tabRegistra"
    private Tab tabRegistra; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Split1"
    private SplitPane Split1; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="MenuBar"
    private MenuBar MenuBar; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="lblAnalisiSing"
    private Label lblAnalisiSing; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btnSpettrogram"
    private Button btnSpettrogram; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btnAnalizza"
    private Button btnAnalizza; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="ColData"
    private TableColumn<PopulateTable, String> colDate; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="GuidaOnline"
    private MenuItem GuidaOnline; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="ColNome"
    private TableColumn<PopulateTable, String> colName; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Table1"
    private TableView<PopulateTable> Table1; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Hbox"
    private HBox Hbox; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btnPulsazioni"
    private Button btnPulsazioni; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btnRimuovi"
    private Button btnRimuovi; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="ColNum"
    private TableColumn<PopulateTable,Integer> colCount; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tabElenco"
    private Tab tabElenco; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="RightStatus"
    private Label RightStatus; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Scroll2"
    private ScrollPane Scroll2; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Scroll1"
    private ScrollPane Scroll1; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Pane"
    private Pane Pane; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="About"
    private MenuItem About; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Anchor1"
    private AnchorPane Anchor1; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Anchor2"
    private AnchorPane Anchor2; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="LeftStatus"
    private Label LeftStatus; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btnAggiungi"
    private Button btnAggiungi; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btnPicchi"
    private Button btnPicchi; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Manuale"
    private MenuItem Manuale; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btnFormanti"
    private Button btnFormanti; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btnIntensita"
    private Button btnIntensita; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Tab1"
    private TabPane Tab1; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="x3"
    private Font x3; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="x4"
    private Color x4; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="VBox"
    private VBox VBox; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Riconoscimenti"
    private MenuItem Riconoscimenti; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="Separator"
    private SeparatorMenuItem Separator; // Value injected by FXMLLoader



    String fileName;

    @FXML
    /**
     * Apertura della finestra fileChooser per il caricamento dei file audio,
     * sono accettati solo file con estensione .wav e .mp3.
     * Estrazione del nome del file.
     * 
     * @param event 
     */
    public void AddFileAudio(ActionEvent event) {
         FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
         fileChooser.setTitle("Seleziona il file da caricare");
         fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                 new ExtensionFilter("Audio Files", "*.wav", "*.mp3"));
         File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());        
         if (selectedFile != null) {
             fileName = selectedFile.getName();
             colName.setText(fileName);

             }

   }


    public ObservableList<PopulateTable>    list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new PopulateTable(1, fileName, "date1"),
            new PopulateTable(2, "name2", "date2"),
            new PopulateTable(3, "name3", "date3")); 


    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resource) {

        colCount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PopulateTable,Integer>("count"));
        colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PopulateTable,String>("name"));
        colDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PopulateTable,String>("date"));
        Table1.setItems(list);

        assert Help != null : "fx:id=\"Help\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert btnSpettro != null : "fx:id=\"btnSpettro\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert lblAnalisiCom != null : "fx:id=\"lblAnalisiCom\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert tabRegistra != null : "fx:id=\"tabRegistra\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Split1 != null : "fx:id=\"Split1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert MenuBar != null : "fx:id=\"MenuBar\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert lblAnalisiSing != null : "fx:id=\"lblAnalisiSing\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert btnSpettrogram != null : "fx:id=\"btnSpettrogram\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert btnAnalizza != null : "fx:id=\"btnAnalizza\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert colDate != null : "fx:id=\"ColData\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert GuidaOnline != null : "fx:id=\"GuidaOnline\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert colName != null : "fx:id=\"ColNome\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Table1 != null : "fx:id=\"Table1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Hbox != null : "fx:id=\"Hbox\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert btnPulsazioni != null : "fx:id=\"btnPulsazioni\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert btnRimuovi != null : "fx:id=\"btnRimuovi\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert colCount != null : "fx:id=\"ColNum\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert tabElenco != null : "fx:id=\"tabElenco\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert RightStatus != null : "fx:id=\"RightStatus\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Scroll2 != null : "fx:id=\"Scroll2\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Scroll1 != null : "fx:id=\"Scroll1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Pane != null : "fx:id=\"Pane\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert About != null : "fx:id=\"About\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Anchor1 != null : "fx:id=\"Anchor1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Anchor2 != null : "fx:id=\"Anchor2\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert LeftStatus != null : "fx:id=\"LeftStatus\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert btnAggiungi != null : "fx:id=\"btnAggiungi\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert btnPicchi != null : "fx:id=\"btnPicchi\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Manuale != null : "fx:id=\"Manuale\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert btnFormanti != null : "fx:id=\"btnFormanti\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert btnIntensita != null : "fx:id=\"btnIntensita\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Tab1 != null : "fx:id=\"Tab1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert x3 != null : "fx:id=\"x3\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert x4 != null : "fx:id=\"x4\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert VBox != null : "fx:id=\"VBox\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Riconoscimenti != null : "fx:id=\"Riconoscimenti\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";
        assert Separator != null : "fx:id=\"Separator\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'StartGUI.fxml'.";

    }

}
```

**this is a utility class PopulateTable**

```
package utility;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class PopulateTable {
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty count;
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;
    private final SimpleStringProperty date;
    public PopulateTable(int count, String name, String date) {
        super();
        this.count = new SimpleIntegerProperty(count);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.date = new SimpleStringProperty(date);
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count.get();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: show us some code for a more efficient help!

Comment: What does "insert it into a table column" mean? Do you want to add data to the table? Or set it as text in the column header? What do you actually mean here? As already asked, can you post some example code to show what you are doing?

Comment: the code is very long. I got through filechooser the filename. I would like to add this filename in a column of a Tableview. how to do?

Comment: You need to create a simple example (i.e. a new project) that shows the issue. It should not take much code to do that. It's really not clear what you are asking: you typically add new rows to a table with `table.getItems().add(...)`, but I can't tell if that's what you really mean. It might help your question if you read "How to create a [MCVE]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
Table1.getItems().add(new PopulateTable(0, fileName, ""));
```

i.e.

```
public void AddFileAudio(ActionEvent event) {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Seleziona il file da caricare");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new ExtensionFilter("Audio Files", "*.wav", "*.mp3"));
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());        
    if (selectedFile != null) {
        String fileName = selectedFile.getName();
        Table1.getItems().add(new PopulateTable(0, fileName, ""));
    }

}
```

(You might need to change the first and third parameter values to something appropriate.)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!! Thank you for availability. It was not easy to explain, but thank you very much!!